# Angular - unable to maintain active class

Tags: javascript, angular, click, dom-events, angular-directive

In this app, In each question, I have 4 statements and in those statements, either True or false can be right answers, that is working fine. But when I click on next statement it removes the class from previously selected element. I want to select either true or false from any statement and it should maintain its active state when I click on next statement's button. What is the way I can handle that? I'm using IDs so I can't think of any workaround. Please any help or suggestions..

**Working Stackblitz Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4yczgp

```
<div class="statement-row"
                               *ngFor="let item of qblock.options;let j = index"
                               [class.correct-answer]="item.id == id && right"
                               [class.wrong-answer]="item.id == id && wrong"
                               >
                               <!-- [ngClass]="{'wrong-answer': item.selectedIndex === j,'correct-answer':item.customIndex === j}" -->
                            <div class="statement-question">
                              <div class="qitem-text">
                                <div class="qitem-textbox">
                                  <p>{{item.statement}}</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ccq">
                                <div class="qitem" [class.green-class-right]="highlight_false_green && item.id == id" [class.red-class-wrong]="highlight_false_red  && item.id == id"
                                        (click)="clickFalse(item)">
                                  <i class="qitembox qclose-icon"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="qitem" [class.green-class-right]="highlight_true_green  && item.id == id" [class.red-class-wrong]="highlight_true_red  && item.id == id"
                                (click)="clickTrue(item)">

                                  <i class="qitembox qtick-icon"></i>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="correct-statement">
                              <span class="true-statement">This statment is True</span>
                              <span class="false-statement">This statment is False</span>
                              <em class="wrong-answer-description">
                                {{item.explanation}}
                              </em>
                              <em class="correct-answer-description">
                                {{item.explanation}}
                              </em>
                            </div>

                          </div>
```

Comment: You need a discreet `highlight_true_red` state variable *for each item*, not just a single one for the entire app. You should also refactor your app so you have a single state variable for each app, I'd use `undefined` if the user hasn't selected anything, and `false`/`true` to store their choice. Using that single variable you can determine all the other information in the render loop.

Comment: since you are setting the option `id`, `right` and `wrong` to the component and refer to it in every question, you either could refactor this logic to generate an object with the data for each question individually and refer to that in your template OR make a sub component for a question and use the current as the "quiz-master-component"

Comment: Hey @Chris, can you show on stackblitz, I don’t have hands-on for angular yet. I’m still learning things

Comment: @Agree please if you can elaborate in stackblitz..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked the component, so I think it works as you want. You can find the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pctp7z

If you have any further questions, please feel free to ask them. It's a bit difficult to describe all the code changes. I hope it helps!

Comment: It works but there's another issue related to this, if you can help with that

Comment: and what is the issue? :)

Comment: I’ve updated my Demo, Added two questions of different type. Tried your solution on those but not working. Those are not t/f but MCQs type. Same issue is occurring, any help?

Comment: I updated mine, guess this is what you was looking for ;)

Comment: can you please help me with another issue?

Comment: i surely can try... ask your question the way you should on stackoverflow and send me the link :)

Comment: It’s my partner’s question. Working on same thing. I hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840491/angular-check-if-all-options-are-selected-to-enable-button